# Possible to use variables in a preseed file?

Tags: environment-variables, preseed

I've created an automated ubuntu image using packer using the `preseed.cfg` file and I realized that we use multiple templates and each one requires the same preseed but a few different values for specific parameters.

Is it possible to create a variable in the preseed to get a value from an environment variable?

If not my workaround might be:

1. Create a replaceable value in `preseed.cfg` like `$CUSTOM_VALUE` and rename the preseed to `preseed.cfg.tpl`
2. Before the packer process, run `sed` against `preseed.cfg.tpl` to replace `$CUSTOM_VALUE` with the environment var value and output the file as `preseed.cfg`
3. Run packer on the new preseed

Another workaround is to use a preprovisioner like [`racker`](https://github.com/aspring/racker) to read the template preseed, replace the value, save it to a file, and then pipe the racker output to packer e.g. `racker ubuntu.rb - | packer build -`

Answer (score 1):

Yes. [bootparam](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/bootparam.7.html) has this important part:

> Anything of the form 'foo=bar' that is not accepted as a setup function as described above is then interpreted as an environment variable to be set.

And appendix B.2.2 of "Automating the installation using preseeding":

> B.2.2. Using boot parameters to preseed questions
>   If a preconfiguration file cannot be used to preseed some steps, the install can still be fully automated, since you can pass preseed values on the command line when booting the installer.
>
> Boot parameters can also be used if you do not really want to use preseeding, but just want to provide an answer for a specific question. Some examples where this can be useful are documented elsewhere in this manual.
>
> To set a value to be used inside debian-installer, just pass path/to/variable=value for any of the preseed variables listed in the examples in this appendix. If a value is to be used to configure packages for the target system, you will need to prepend the owner ( The owner of a debconf variable (or template) is normally the name of the package that contains the corresponding debconf template. For variables used in the installer itself the owner is “d-i”. Templates and variables can have more than one owner which helps to determine whether they can be removed from the debconf database if the package is purged.) of the variable as in owner:path/to/variable=value. If you don't specify the owner, the value for the variable will not be copied to the debconf database in the target system and thus remain unused during the configuration of the relevant package.
>
> Normally, preseeding a question in this way will mean that the question will not be asked. To set a specific default value for a question, but still have the question asked, use “?=” instead of “=” as operator. See also Section B.5.2, “Using preseeding to change default values”.
>
> Note that some variables that are frequently set at the boot prompt have a shorter alias. If an alias is available, it is used in the examples in this appendix instead of the full variable. The preseed/url variable for example has been aliased as url. Another example is the tasks alias, which translates to tasksel:tasksel/first.
>
> **Note**: Current linux kernels (2.6.9 and later) accept a maximum of 32 command line options and 32 environment options, including any options added by default for the installer. If these numbers are exceeded, the kernel will panic (crash). (For earlier kernels, these numbers were lower.)
>
> **Note**: The ubuntu.parmfile is limited to 11 lines only, each 80 characters long. (The precise limit is 11 lines with each * 80 characters plus additional 10 characters.) Hence it's recommended to try specifying more than just one parameter per line, separate parameters by single spaces and use as much (shortened) aliases as possible. But do not specify a single parameter (incl. it's value) across multiple lines! The case of the parameter as well as the sequence don't matter.

And B.2.4 has a list of aliases:

> B.2.4. Aliases useful with preseeding
>   The following aliases can be useful when using (auto mode) preseeding. Note that these are simply short aliases for question names, and you always need to specify a value as well: for example, auto=true or interface=eth0.

```
priority    debconf/priority
fb          debian-installer/framebuffer
language    debian-installer/language
country     debian-installer/country
locale      debian-installer/locale
theme       debian-installer/theme
auto        auto-install/enable
classes     auto-install/classes
file        preseed/file
url         preseed/url
domain      netcfg/get_domain
hostname    netcfg/get_hostname
interface   netcfg/choose_interface
protocol    mirror/protocol
suite       mirror/suite
modules     anna/choose_modules
recommends  base-installer/install-recommends
tasks       tasksel:tasksel/first
desktop     tasksel:tasksel/desktop
dmraid      disk-detect/dmraid/enable
keymap      keyboard-configuration/xkb-keymap
preseed-md5 preseed/file/checksum
```

Comment: Hope you don't mind those tabs in code blocks always drive me nuts and my OCD made me edit and fix :)

Comment: I'm still kind of confused by this. I'm running the preseed with the `auto`, `priority`, `locale`, and a few other aliases according to that documentation but I'd like to parameterize custom values. I'm sure your description is correct but could you provide an example on how to use this? @Rinzwind