# How to use classes in a preseed file

Tags: system-installation, preseed

Following up with [Possible to use variables in a preseed file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1160799/possible-to-use-variables-in-a-preseed-file), and https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/s390x/apbs02.html, which says:

> In addition to specifying the url, you can also specify settings that do not directly affect the behavior of debian-installer itself, but can be passed through to scripts specified using preseed/run in the loaded preseed file. At present, the only example of this is auto-install/classes, which has an alias classes. This can be used thus:
>
> ```
> auto url=example.com classes=class_A;class_B
> ```
>
> The classes could for example denote the type of system to be installed, or the localization to be used.

So suppose that I've typed the following at the boot prompt:

`auto url=example.com classes=class_A;class_B`

How to make use of the passed `classes` in my preseed file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$classes` variable will be part of the installer environment and available in any scripts that are run.  It could be used directly in `preseed/early_command` or `preseed/late_command`, and would be available in scripts referenced in `preseed/run`.

For example, this preseed snippet will simply create a file with the `$classes` variable content.  It will also output the `env` to a file so you can see what variables are available by default.  You can access the files during install using the console accessed with `alt-f2`.

```
d-i preseed/early_command string \
  env > /run/my_env ; \
  echo $classes > /run/my_classes ;
```

Be careful using a semicolon (`;`) in your boot command line as it may be seen as the end of the command line.  I suggest a different delimiter character.

The [Advanced Options page](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/amd64/apbs05.html) provides some more details and may give you some ideas on how to use the variables you define.